# Web Database - How to store user information

Tags: database-design

I'm starting to design a database to use in a web solution and would like to understand if there is any benefit to storing passwords (and the rest of the user information for that matter) in a separate table to the table with the user id.

Comment: None that I can think of. What's the premise of the notion?

Comment: You could use OpenID or OAuth and then never have to store the password

Answer (score 4):

The one benefit for storing passwords in a separate table, if you have a db that supports this, is you can use a security definer function to read the passwords, and this prevents sql injection or the like from reading it in other queries.  Think of it as being like the /etc/shadow file on Linux.  Of course this is in addition to salted hashes.

This being said I am of the opinion you should really avoid storing passwords in your database.  The less of this sort of thing your app does the less you have to worry about security-wise.  Outsource it to OpenID providers, etc. or if it is an intranet app, something like LDAP, AD, or the like.

Answer (score 1):

There was a school of thought that said you should try to make user credentials hard to find in your database to make it harder for hackers to get at this information.

I think that this is ultimately wrong-minded, because once a hacker gets into your database it's not going to be much of a problem for them to unload your data and figure out what it is, regardless of how many tables you've got and how much trouble you've gone to spreading columns around.

**The right place to thwart hackers is outside your firewall.**  You should keep your database schema as simple as possible to make it efficient and maintainable and take all of the necessary precautions to keep hackers from getting *any* access to your database.

One other thing you should do by way of keeping sensitive data safe is to **encrypt sensitive data**.  Don't keep things like passwords or credit card numbers in plain text.  Use strong encryption for these kinds of data elements.